# Rails: select in an intricate relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, relationship, named-scope

I am rather new to rails, so I ask for your patience.

I have a bit of an intricate relationship between three (ActiveRecord) models:

```
class Producer
  has_many :clients
end  

class Client
  belongs_to :producer
  has_many   :products
end

class Product
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :producer
end
```

The producer of a particluar product is not necessarily the same as the producer of the products client (but he can be).

I need to somehow select/scope all the products of a producer, where he is not the producer of that products client . I cannot wrap my head around that. I am trying to think in the line of producer != producer.products.clients.producer which of course doesn' work or make sense.

Please help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.includes(:producer, :client).
   where("products.producer_id" => X).
   where( "clients.producer.id != products.producer_id")
```

will find the products from producer with id X as you wanted.

Comment: I get a syntax error at the Not keyword and at the last closing parenthesis. /app/controllers/producers_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...here( "clients.producer.id" Not => "products.producer_id")
...                               ^
/app/controllers/producers_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
... Not => "products.producer_id")
...                               ^

Comment: ok this doesn't cause a syntax error, but blows up because I did not mention that both client and producer are subclasses of contact in a single table inheritance... Sorry. I have to do some kind of self join with different type attributes (one producer one client).

Answer (score 1):

```
@products = Product.select("products.*").joins(:clients).joins(:producers).where("products.producer_id = ? AND clients.producer_id != ?", producer_id, producer_id)
```

should give you the required result.

Hope it helps !